# Install selective features in WiX

Tags: dialog, wix

I have an MSI with 2 features nested inside a parent feature. It has a default UI. During the first installation, I chose to install the first feature only and not the second feature. So, the first feature gets installed properly. Then when I click on the MSI and install again, from the Change option, I chose to install the second feature only. But this uninstalls the first one and installs the second. What I expected was, it will retain the first feature and install the second feature, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In another case, I tried with custom UI for the features with check boxes. Here, when I selected one feature and install it, it gets installed, but when I ran the installer again and chose the second feature, only the first feature is installed, but the second feature doesn't get installed.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

When you ran the MSI from change mode, the change that the MSI is going to take is the same of the view (FeatureSelection), if you check a feature this say you want to install it or you want to leave this installed(if this are ready installed), if you uncheck it, what the MSI understand is you don't want to install this or you want to uninstall this featere(if this is installed).

This is working properly.

What do you want to do, do not have much sense, because you dont have a way to say to the MSI to uninstall a feature after this is installed.